# How to disable Csrf Protection for API in CakePHP 5?

Tags: rest, cakephp, csrf

If you added API prefix routing and want to disable Csrf Protection for POST, PUT API requests then follow the below listed steps.

First add API prefix routing into `config/routes.php`

```
$routes->prefix('api', function (RouteBuilder $routes): void {
          $routes->setExtensions(['json', 'xml'])
          $routes->connect(
            '/token',
            ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'token']
            )->setMethods(['POST']);
          $routes->resources('Users');
          $routes->resources('Pages');
      });
```

Now update `src/Application.php`.

```
public function middleware(MiddlewareQueue $middlewareQueue): MiddlewareQueue
    {

        $csrf = new CsrfProtectionMiddleware(['httponly' => true]);

        // Disable CSRF for API
        // Token check will be skipped when callback returns `true`.
        $csrf->skipCheckCallback(function ($request) {
            // Skip token check for API URLs.
            if ($request->getParam('prefix') === 'Api') {
                return true;
            }
        });
        .
        .
        .
        .
        ->add($csrf);
        return $middlewareQueue;
    }
```

I tried above code and it is working.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you mean by "it's not working" ? Edit your question so other can better understand what happens